# Running if/each statement to select divs and alter background image position independently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently trying to change the position of a background image within a div depending on the text within a span.

My problem is multiple divs have the same class which are not changeable.

For example. Every cell where I want to change the image position looks like:

```
<td class="js-gridBlock js-Pre-order" data-attvalue1="3XL" data-attvalue2="Plum">
  <div class="js-gridImage">
    <div class="prodpageGridText" id="gridtext-gridbox34">
      <span class="status">Due in 4 weeks</span><br>
      <div class="prodpageGridTextArrow">
      </div>
     </div>
   </div>
</td>
```

Where the Span class Status value changes anywhere between 1-10.

My jQuery currently looks like;

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      if (jQuery('span.status:contains("4")')) {
            jQuery('.js-Pre-order .js-gridImage').css("background-position", "-4px -213px"); 
        } 
      if (jQuery('span.status:contains("5")')) {
            jQuery('.js-Pre-order .js-gridImage').css("background-position", "-4px -242px"); 
        }
     if (jQuery('span.status:contains("10")')) {
            jQuery('.js-Pre-order .js-gridImage').css("background-position", "-4px -387px"); 
        }
    });
```

My issue is when the jQuery is run every js-gridImage then changes to `("background-position", "-4px -387px")` where as I need them to change dependent on their spanvalues.

I have seen the .each() function but am unsure how best to incorporate it into my code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the relationship between elements, Here [`.closest(selector)`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/#closest1) can be used to traverse up to fetch the desired element and set the CSS rules.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('span.status:contains("4")').closest('.js-gridImage').css("background-position", "-4px -213px"); 
    jQuery('span.status:contains("5")').closest('.js-gridImage').css("background-position", "-4px -242px"); 
    jQuery('span.status:contains("10")').closest('.js-gridImage').css("background-position", "-4px -387px"); 
});
```

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you very much!